# My question is about calculating an indicator based on column total using DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table given below. I want to create an indicator which will be based on the column total using DAX. E.g Company A with YoY 13% would have an indicator value 1  as it is more than equal to YoY column total of 8%. I want the similar indicator for all the companies. It should automatically change based on filter/slicer values in Power BI

```
Company Pax 2019    YoY(%)  
A   87  13% 
B   45  9%  
C   57  9%  
D   82  2%  
E   53  4%  
F   57  8%  
G   84  12% 
Grand Total 465 8%
```

I tried it using all table but it changes as the filter changes the value.

```
Company Pax 2019    YoY(%)  Indicator(if grand total YoY> individual YoY, 1, 0)
A   87  13% 1
B   45  9%  1
C   57  9%  1
D   82  2%  0
E   53  4%  0
F   57  8%  0
G   84  12% 1
Grand Total 465 8%
```

Comment: posting your measure formula would be helpful.

Comment: My measure formula was not working at all.  indicator 2 = CALCULATE([Pax YoY(%)],ALL('Issue vs Departure')) and used this indicator against each value. dint work.

Comment: What does the code of [Pax YoY(%)] look like?

Comment: Pax YoY(%) = (CALCULATE(sum('ID'[Flights]),'ID'[Issue year]=2019)-CALCULATE(sum('ID'[Flights]),'ID'[Issue year]=2018))/CALCULATE(sum('ID'[Flights]),'ID'[Issue year]=2018)

Comment: Now I want to create measure which should give me 1 or 0 if Pax YoY(%) is  less than column total value of Pax YoY(%) for each category data

Answer (score 0):

Below DAX Expression should work for you:

```
Column =
VAR Tot_Average =
    AVERAGE ( 'Example'[Pax] )
VAR Check =
    CALCULATE (
        Tot_Average,
        ALL ( 'Example'[Pax] )
    )
RETURN
    IF ( 'Example'[Pax] > Check, 1, 0 )
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, it is not working. Let me rephrase the questions.

Comment: Can you comment what was the output of this DAX expression?